# Setting version information of multiple C++ DLLS

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to set/update version information of multiple C++ DLLs in my project.
I was thinking of having a common version info resource (.rc) file. I can update version details in this rc file, build it to compiled resource (.res) file, and set all C++ DLL projects to link to this .res file. 
But version info also contains other information like "FileDescription", "FileName" which will be different for each DLL.
Is there any solution to set version information of multiple C++ DLLs in single step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing Version Resources in Visual Studio C++ (Win32) Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894329/synchronizing-version-resources-in-visual-studio-c-win32-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How we do it is to have a file called "version.rc2" in our common include path and then we #include that file in every projects .rc2 file. Right before the #include "version.rc2" in the project .rc2 file we also #include a file called ProjVerInfo.h that is defined in each and every project that #defines FILE_DESCRIPTION, INTERNAL_NAME, and ORIGINAL_NAME for each project. When the version.rc2 file is #included for each project, these pieces of text will be substituted into all the version info.

Comment: This is how I handle it, works well for many DLLs. My build is actually set up to build a regular C/++ header with git revision and version number `#define`d, then all the resources `#include` that (as do some source code files, for stamping the logs).

Comment: Still useful info 10 years after the question was asked. I'm now using this for several projects.